# synchronous call httpclienthandler does not wait

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I do a call to the following, but I notice that if the webapi i'm calling takes longer than 41 seconds it will just return leading to a null value.

I tried setting the client.timeout setting but that did not seem to make a difference. What am I doing wrong?

```
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Credentials = credentials
            };            
        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.Timeout.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(site.ToString());
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            try
            {
                string target = site.ToString() + apiPath + query;
                var response = client.GetAsync(target).Result;                   
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result =                            
                        response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                    else
                    {       
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {                 
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {             
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe it's the API that's not returning anything? Have you checked with a sniffer?

Comment: That's working, (a) when i call it via powershell i do get the result after about 1.5 minute and (b) via the nlogs I see that about 30 seconds later stuff is happening in the web api (so after it already timed out) (the target web api just continues).

Comment: *"so after it already timed out"* you're setting a timeout of 1 hour 1 minute 40 seconds (`client.Timeout.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));`), how can it be already timed out after 1 minute 30 seconds?

Comment: BTW `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` is useless, [`EnsureSuccessStatusCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode.aspx) throws an exception is the status code is not a successful one.

Comment: after 41 seconds it falls into the exception, so on this one: var result =                            
                        response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; with the Exception Message multiple errors occured. Calling the web api directly or with different parameters that lead to something less than 41 seconds works ok.

Comment: HttpClient has an async only API. Calling `.Result` like this dangerous and deadlock-inviting. Use `await`, and if you absolutely can't for some reason, use something with synchronous support like WebClient or RestSharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`client.Timeout.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));`

does nothing, because TimeSpan is immutable.  It just returns a value, which you then don't use.  I presume you instead want:

`client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);`